# Two objects calling the same function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I was wondering if its possible to have two objects store the same function in it. When I load this into the browser, object1 runs automatically.  I want the function to be used in multiple places, but also not run until it is called.  Thanks!

```
var myFunction = function(){
//runs code
};

var object1 = {
      key1 : myFunction()
};

var object2 = {
      key1 : myFunction()
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the function itself, simply don't call it:

```
var object1 = {
      key1 : myFunction
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! but what if i need to pass a parameter into the function?

then it would be object1.key1(parameter)?

Comment: @Rob: Yes; you call it just like you would call any other function.